# Python Random Int Generation returning 'None' instead of a integer

Tags: python, random, nonetype, dice

I have a very simple dice rolling program, with the main body of the program here.

```
import random
from time import sleep

rounds = 5
delay = 1

playerTwoScore = 30
playerOneScore = 20

def roll():
 rollOne = random.randint(1,6)
 rollTwo = random.randrange(1,6)
 if rollOne == rollTwo:
   score = (rollOne + rollTwo) * 2
 else:
   score = rollOne + rollTwo
   return score


for i in range(rounds):
 playerOneRoll = roll()
 print("Player 1 rolled a",playerOneRoll)
 playerOneScore = int(playerOneScore) + int(playerOneRoll)
 print("Player 1's total score is",playerOneScore)
 print("----------------------------")
 sleep(delay)
 roll()
 playerTwoRoll = roll()
 print("Player 2 rolled a",playerTwoRoll)
 playerTwoScore = int(playerTwoScore) + int(playerTwoRoll)
 print("Player 2's total score is",playerTwoScore)
 print("----------------------------")
 sleep(delay)
```

It works fine for a couple rounds but then sometimes the player one roll will return as `None` and the program will end due to an error. Can't figure out why. The image of the output:

[image: output]

Any comments or ideas about this would help a lot - many thanks.

Comment: You only `return` in the `else`. You probably meant the `return` line to be dedented, so it's outside the `else`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You need to return something for the "equal" possibility

Otherwise, on the 1/6 of occasions with equal rollOne and rollTwo, the function will return without a value, i.e. None.

#### Also there is no need to do the extra `roll`

You aren't storing the result.

#### Fixed code:

```
rounds = 10
delay = 1
import random
from time import sleep
playerOneScore = 0
playerTwoScore = 0

def roll():
 rollOne = random.randint(1,6)
 rollTwo = random.randrange(1,6)
 if rollOne == rollTwo:
   return (rollOne + rollTwo) * 2  # <---- Need to return this
 else:
   return rollOne + rollTwo


for i in range(rounds):
 playerOneRoll = roll()
 print("Player 1 rolled a",playerOneRoll)
 playerOneScore = int(playerOneScore) + int(playerOneRoll)
 print("Player 1's total score is",playerOneScore)
 print("----------------------------")
 sleep(delay)
 roll()           #     <---- not needed
 playerTwoRoll = roll()
 print("Player 2 rolled a",playerTwoRoll)
 playerTwoScore = int(playerTwoScore) + int(playerTwoRoll)
 print("Player 2's total score is",playerTwoScore)
 print("----------------------------")
 sleep(delay)
```